# undefined property on iterator_to_array (date object)

Tags: php, date, iterator

With this snippet:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$periods = new DatePeriod($dt, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6);
$days = iterator_to_array($periods);
foreach($days as $day){
    echo 'current date: '.$day->date.'<br />';
}
```

I see this error:

> Notice: Undefined property: DateTime::$date

Anyway, If I add a "print_r" before echo:

```
$dt = new DateTime();
$periods = new DatePeriod($dt, new DateInterval('P1D'), 6);
$days = iterator_to_array($periods);
foreach($days as $day){
    print_r($day);
    echo 'current date: '.$day->date.'<br />';
}
```

I see on my page both the print_r result and the result of echo.
Why?

Comment: You should use `$date->format()` [PHP DateTime::format](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, it might be a bug. But you'll need to use your `$day` object like this only:

```
foreach($days as $day){
    echo $day->format('Y-m-d')."\n";
}
```

I'm guessing printing the `$day` object initializes it somehow, and you're able to use its member variables then.

PS. you don't really need to iterator_to_array to iterate through the `DatePeriod` object. You can simply do something like `foreach ($periods as $day)`

Comment: With `foreach ($periods as $day)`, I receive the same Notice.
With day->format, it works fine.

Comment: You shouldn't receive a notice, the example on the php.net site uses that loop only.  Anyway, as long as your code works :)